# How can I check if a file exists or not to delete it and create it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello I have an error as it does not find a file but I do not understand, if someone could help me =)

```
if (choice == "txt") {
            const dataWhitelist = await whitelists.find({ 'guildId': interaction.guild.id });
            const nameFile = interaction.guild.id + '.txt';
            if (fs.existsSync(`./tmp/${nameFile}`)) {
                fs.unlinkSync(`./tmp/${nameFile}`)
            }
            for (const i in dataWhitelist) {
                fs.appendFile(`./tmp/${nameFile}`, dataWhitelist[i].userId + ',' + dataWhitelist[i].address + ';', function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    } else {
                        // done
                    }
                })
            }
            interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
            interaction.followUp({ content: `Here is the export for your server.`, files: [{ attachment: `./tmp/${nameFile}` }] });
        }
```

and this is the error I get when I make my commands

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/user/bots/whitelister_mongoose/tmp/859055688965816320.txt'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/user/bots/whitelister_mongoose/tmp/859055688965816320.txt'
}
```

Comment: Appending to the same file multiple times in parallel is probably not a good idea. While the exact error is peculiar, I wouldn't rule out that it's same bizarre edge case behavior of the OS that comes from doing that. Use `appendFileSync` or (better) rewrite the whole function to be asynchronous.

Comment: Do you have an idea to switch it to asynchronous? @CherryDT

Comment: You already seem to have an async function there so you just need to use `await fs.promises.<whatever>` instead of `fs.<whatever>Sync` (and also use `await fs.promises.appendFile`). Special case is just the `exists` that doesn't have a promise version (you would have to use `stat` instead and catch its error) but for that it's probably easier to not check for existence at all and just catch and ignore the error that `unlink` may throw if it's `ENOENT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with CherryDT that the error you got is probably due to parallel appending to the same file multiple times. You can try the asynchronous version below:

```js
if (choice == "txt") {
  const dataWhitelist = await whitelists.find({ 'guildId': interaction.guild.id });
  const nameFile = interaction.guild.id + '.txt';
  try {
    await fs.promises.unlink(`./tmp/${nameFile}`);
    for await (const i in dataWhitelist) {
      await fs.promises.appendFile(`./tmp/${nameFile}`, dataWhitelist[i].userId + ',' + dataWhitelist[i].address + ';');
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
  interaction.followUp({ content: `Here is the export for your server.`, files: [{ attachment: `./tmp/${nameFile}` }] });
}
```